# Data modeling localization issue

Tags: database, localization, data-modeling

Say I have a product with attributes - id,name,UPC,price
You can see it as a database table 'product'.

Now I'm having issues wrapping my head around this problem.
Say this same product can be in the UK so the - name, UPC, price might be different.

It would make sense to do one product table for USA, and another for the UK but it sounds redundant. Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

You could do a price table where the key is product id and a location. You could add other dimensions in there as well. e.g. maybe some prices are sensitive to time of year?

Comment: That's a good idea but what about other attributes like name, UPC? They should have their own tables too? Hmm. Sounds like a lot of tables. I left out a description attribute. It may be in a different language depending on the country, maybe having different localized product tables is the simpler solution.

Comment: AFAIK UPC code is UPC code. Name, price, description - yes those would differ. Almost to the point of having separate tables. Tough problem.